# JQuery: TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'attr'

Tags: jquery, attributes, css-selectors, href

This is the code I'm trying to run to "select" the href attribute of every .insite elements of my page:

```
$('.insite').each(function(a) {
    a.attr('href');
});
```

Unfortunately it fails and return me the following error:

> Object 0 has no method 'attr'

Is there anything wrong in what I did?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The callback passed to `.each()` [takes parameters `(index, Element)`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), but you forgot the index. Try:

```
$('.insite').each(function(i, a) {
    alert(a.attr('href'));
});
```

or just:

```
$('.insite').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using 'a', go with 'this'

e.g.

```
$('.insite').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('.insite').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('href');
    // i is the current number of the element in collection
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your var called "a" is just an iteration var so you can't just type a.attr.

If you really want to use "a" you should do something like that :

```
$('.insite').each(function(a) {
var obj = $('.insite')[a];
alert($(obj).attr("href"));
});
```

but I think something like this is really better :

```
$('.insite').each(function() {
$(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: `.each()` already gives you an element reference in the second parameter to the callback. No need for _another_ DOM traversal.